# Is there way to pivot_longer to multiple values columns in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tibble

I'm trying to use pivot_longer to enlongate my dataframe, but I don't need it to be fully long, and would like to output multiple "values" columns.

Example:

```
df <- tibble(
  ids = c("protein1", "protein2"),
  mean.group1 = sample(1:1000, 2),
  mean.group2 = sample(1:1000, 2),
  se.group1 = sample(1:10, 2),
  se.group2 = sample(1:10, 2)
)

df
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ids      mean.group1 mean.group2 se.group1 se.group2
  <chr>          <int>       <int>     <int>     <int>
1 protein1         763         456         6         4
2 protein2         820         624         4         7
```

My desired output is:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  ids = c("protein1", "protein1", "protein2", "protein2"),
  mean = c(df$mean.group1[1], df$mean.group2[1], df$mean.group1[2], df$mean.group2[2]),
  se = c(df$se.group1[1], df$se.group2[1], df$se.group1[2], df$se.group2[2]),
  group = c("group1", "group2", "group1", "group2")
)

df2

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ids       mean    se group 
  <chr>    <int> <int> <chr> 
1 protein1   763     6 group1
2 protein1   456     4 group2
3 protein2   820     4 group1
4 protein2   624     7 group2
```

So far, I have tried multiple subsequent `pivot_longer()` followed by `unique()`, but this is messing up the output:

```
df_longer <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("mean."),
               names_to = "group",
               names_prefix = "mean.",
               values_to = "mean") %>%
  unique() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("se."),
               names_to = "group",
               names_prefix = "se.",
               values_to = "se",
               names_repair = "unique") %>%
  unique()

df_longer

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  ids      group...2  mean group...4    se
  <chr>    <chr>     <int> <chr>     <int>
1 protein1 group1      763 group1        6
2 protein1 group1      763 group2        4
3 protein1 group2      456 group1        6
4 protein1 group2      456 group2        4
5 protein2 group1      820 group1        4
6 protein2 group1      820 group2        7
7 protein2 group2      624 group1        4
8 protein2 group2      624 group2        7
```

I sort of understand why - the rows are being duplicated too many times, and thus the group identity is not being kept for each row. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. I'm aware that there's a `names_pattern` option but I'm not sure how it would apply in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated! I've considered pivoting to fully long format (i.e. having a "measurement" column for each 'mean', 'se', etc) and then using `pivot_wider()` to pivot to the format I need, but I also haven't been able to figure out how to do that. As well, let me know if any more information is needed. My actual dataset deals with 4 different measurements (same format, i.e. measurement.group) and thousands of proteins, but the principle should be the same, I hope!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We don't need multiple calls if we specify the `names_to` as a vector of values i.e. `.value` - returns the value of the columns and 'group' the column with the suffix of column names.  Here, we use `names_sep` as `.` to split at the `.`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols  = -ids, names_to = c(".value", "group"), 
    names_sep = "\\.")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ids      group   mean    se
  <chr>    <chr>  <int> <int>
1 protein1 group1   982     3
2 protein1 group2   657     7
3 protein2 group1   663     9
4 protein2 group2   215     1
```

NOTE: values are different as `sample` was used in creation of input data without a `set.seed` specified