# Calculate percentage of responses for each column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like this

```
User <-c('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4','User_5')
Q1 <- c('Never', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Always') 
Q2<- c('Sometimes', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Rarely')
Q3 <- c('Always', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Always', 'Rarely')
data1 <- data.frame(User, Q1, Q2, Q3)
print(data1)
```

Output

```
    User        Q1        Q2        Q3
1 User_1     Never Sometimes    Always
2 User_2    Rarely    Rarely    Rarely
3 User_3 Sometimes Sometimes Sometimes
4 User_4     Often     Often    Always
5 User_5    Always    Rarely    Rarely
```

My goal is to create a data frame that shows the percentage of each ordinal value for the data set. So that would look something like this:

```
          Q1        Q2        Q3
Never     20%        0%        0%
Rarely    20%       40%       40%
Sometimes 20%       40%       20%
Often     20%       20%        0%
Always    20%        0%       40%
```

I have no idea how to go about this. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
facs <- c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always")
data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -User) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels = facs)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n,
    values_fill = 0L) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~ 100 * . / sum(.)))
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   value        Q1    Q2    Q3
#   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Never        20     0     0
# 2 Rarely       20    40    40
# 3 Sometimes    20    40    20
# 4 Often        20    20     0
# 5 Always       20     0    40
```

Walk-through:

- create `facs` then `factor(values, levels=facs)` so that the premise of "order" in your ordinal scale is preserved and easily sorted
- reshape from wide to long so that we easily `count` the `name` and `value` pairs
- reshape from long to wide again, using `value` on the "left", and question number across the top
- for each of the `Q*` columns, normalize to a 0-100 scale

Refs for pivoting:

- pivot wide-to-long: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272;) (names_pattern) [Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272;) (multiple value columns) [pivot_longer into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272), [Is there way to pivot_longer to multiple values columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272)
- pivot long-to-wide: [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272), [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272)

BTW, you said that there might be masking; in your case, switch to `dplyr::count(..)` (this should not be necessary for others).

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions: 1: How would I do this without using the starts_with() function? In my actual data set, the column names don't have any common labelling. 2:  When I run it with the sample code above, I get 'Error in count(., name, value) : Argument 'x' is not a vector: list'

Comment: (!) You can replace `across(starts_with("Q"), ...)` with `across(c(var1, col2, field3), ...)`. (2) No idea, it works with the sample data provided. Perhaps post the output from `dput(head(yourdata,20))` into your question?

Comment: (that `(!)` was supposed to be `(1)` :-/)

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work, I think it was a masking issue. If I replace `count(name, value)` with `dplyr::count(name, value)` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Percent crosstab in wps/sas uses normalization and r uses initial denormalized data?

see
github
https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-percent-crosstab-in-wps-r

This is a very common problem.

Perhaps normalization is a better initial structure for this data.
Many SAS procedures can summarize normalized data easily, ie procs: SQL, freq, tabulate, report, means, corresp and summary.
I expect the same issue with R packages.

I have examples of all of the repos below.

```
 1 wps proc corresp
 2 R
   https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans
 3 related repos
```