# Add row that is the sum of two other rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame produced in this manner:

```
User <-c('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4','User_5')
Q1 <- c('Never', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Always') 
Q2<- c('Sometimes', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Rarely')
Q3 <- c('Always', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Always', 'Rarely')
data1 <- data.frame(User, Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

I have used it to produce a data frame that shows the percentage of each ordinal value for the data set as follows (original solution provided in [Calculate percentage of responses for each column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039266/calculate-percentage-of-responses-for-each-column-in-r/77039324#77039324)):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
facs <- c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always")
data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -User) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels = facs)) %>%
  dplyr::count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n,
    values_fill = 0L) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~ 100 * . / sum(.)))
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   value        Q1    Q2    Q3
#   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Never        20     0     0
# 2 Rarely       20    40    40
# 3 Sometimes    20    40    20
# 4 Often        20    20     0
# 5 Always       20     0    40
```

I would like to add a new row that is the sum of the 'Often' and 'Always' rows. That would look like:

```
#   value        Q1    Q2    Q3
#   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Never        20     0     0
# 2 Rarely       20    40    40
# 3 Sometimes    20    40    20
# 4 Often        20    20     0
# 5 Always       20     0    40
# 6 Super Often  40    20    40
```

How should I do this? I can't seem to find an applicable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store the interim result in a new variable, `summarize` on that frame, then `bind_rows` with it.

```r
data2 <- data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -User) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels = facs)) %>%
  dplyr::count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n,
    values_fill = 0L) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~ 100 * . / sum(.)))

data2 %>%
  filter(value %in% c("Often", "Always")) %>%
  summarize(value = "Super Often", across(c(Q1, Q2, Q3), sum)) %>%
  bind_rows(data2, .)
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   value          Q1    Q2    Q3
#   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Never          20     0     0
# 2 Rarely         20    40    40
# 3 Sometimes      20    40    20
# 4 Often          20    20     0
# 5 Always         20     0    40
# 6 Super Often    40    20    40
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it seems like you have mixed up variables and observations. If the variables you are interested in are the answer categories, they should be columns, not rows:

```
out <- data1 |> 
  pivot_longer(-User, names_to = "Q") |> 
  count(Q, value) |> 
  mutate(n = 100*n/sum(n), .by = Q) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) |>
  mutate(`Super Often` = `Often` + `Always`)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  name  Always Never Often Rarely Sometimes `Super Often`
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Q1        20    20    20     20        20            40
2 Q2         0     0    20     40        40            20
3 Q3        40     0     0     40        20            40
```

If you want to transpose it back, you can use:

```
out |>
 pivot_longer(-Q, names_to = "A") |>
 pivot_wider(names_from = Q)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  A              Q1    Q2    Q3
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Always         20     0    40
2 Never          20     0     0
3 Often          20    20     0
4 Rarely         20    40    40
5 Sometimes      20    40    20
6 Super Often    40    20    40
```

Answer (score 0):

And for good measure, a base R approach:

```
# identify where to add new row
add_idx <- nrow(data1_trans)+1

# create new factor level since `value` is a factor
data1_trans$value <- factor(data1_trans$value, levels = c(levels(data1_trans$value), "Superoften"))

#add rows
data1_trans[add_idx, 1] <- "Superoften"
data1_trans[add_idx, -1] <- rbind(colSums(data1_trans[data1_trans$value %in% c("Often", "Always"),-1]))
```

Output:

```
 value         Q1    Q2    Q3
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Never         20     0     0
2 Rarely        20    40    40
3 Sometimes     20    40    20
4 Often         20    20     0
5 Always        20     0    40
6 superoften    40    20    40
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `data2` is the input as in the Note at the end, here are several approaches:

**1) add_row** Add a column which is TRUE for `Often` or `Always`, use `add_row` to add the desired row and then remove the added column.

```
library(dplyr)

data3 <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(super = value %in% c("Often", "Always")) %>%
  reframe(add_row(., value = "Super often", across(-1, ~ sum(super * .)))) %>%
  select(-super) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, value))
data3
## # A tibble: 6 × 4
##   value          Q1    Q2    Q3
##   <fct>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 Never          20     0     0
## 2 Rarely         20    40    40
## 3 Sometimes      20    40    20
## 4 Often          20    20     0
## 5 Always         20     0    40
## 6 Super often    40    20    40
```

**2) adorn_totals** As in (1) add a `super` column and then use `adorn_totals`.  Then remomve the row and column we don't need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

data4 <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(super = value %in% c("Often", "Always")) %>%
  group_modify(~ adorn_totals(., name = "Super often")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(super | value != "Super often") %>%
  select(-super) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, value))

identical(data4, data3)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

The input

```
data2 <- tibble::tibble(
  value = factor(
    c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always"),
    levels = c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always")
  ),
  Q1 = rep(20, 5L),
  Q2 = c(0, 40, 40, 20, 0),
  Q3 = c(0, 40, 20, 0, 40),
)
```