# Dodged Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill

I am trying to make a dodged bar chart (ggplot) using a data set containing county level vaccination data. I want my x axis to be the 2 counties and I want to fill based on specific column names (based on the race in the column). I am not sure what I should put as my y-axis. I think I need to rotate the data set and add a column with race to then use that to fill the data. But not sure how to do that.

I have tried to rotate the data but am not able to make the first row the column names.
[image: current code]
[image: Data set]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Added images, working on example

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: I like to use and suggest https://https://r-graph-gallery.com as a picture-menu of `ggplot2` plots along with the code and data to reproduce them. As for reshaping from wide-to-long, the best I can do lacking sample data is a list of good Q/As here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272; (names_pattern) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; (multiple value columns) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272. Good luck!

Comment: My guess is something like `pivot_longer(ms_1, cols=-COUNTRY_NAME)` which will produce a frame with three columns: `COUNTRY_NAME` (same contents but now many more rows), `name` with `c("COUNT_TOTAL", "COUNT_ETH_NHL", ...)`, and `value` with `c(106,27,5,7,...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation your are looking for is called “reshaping” or “pivoting”.
The `tidyr` package provides `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` for
that purpose. Below is an exampple of how to `pivot_longer()` your
data and create a bar plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Creating parts of your dataset with random numbers.
# (As some of the commenters pointed out, it would be better
# if you could include your data in your question 
# in a reproducible fashion.)
ms_1 <- tibble(
  COUNTY_NAME = c("Alleghany", "Montgomery", "Total"),
  COUNT_TOTAL = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_ETH_NHL = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_ETH_HL = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_ETH_UNKNOWN = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_RACE_AIAN = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_RACE_ASIAN = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_RACE_BLACK = sample(50:500, 3),
  COUNT_RACE_WHITE = sample(50:500, 3),
)

# Pivot, filter, select data and plot bars.
ms_1 |> 
  # Remove the following line if you want to include Total in the plot
  filter(COUNTY_NAME != "Total") |>
  select(COUNTY_NAME, contains("_RACE_")) |> 
  pivot_longer(-COUNTY_NAME, names_to = "race", values_to = "count") |> 
  mutate(race = str_remove(race, "COUNT_RACE_")) |> 
  ggplot(aes(COUNTY_NAME, count, group = race, fill = race)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked thank you! What would the advantage of using |> vs %>% be?

Comment: `|>` or the "base pipe" is supported in R since 4.1.0 without loading a package. It is recommended to use the base pipe instead of the magrittr pipe `%>%` unless you are making use of some of the advanced features the magrittr pipe has to offer. [More on that topic here.](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/)