# Rearrange and align columns based on matching values in data frame using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame in R, and I want to rearrange the columns based on matching values within each column. However, in many cases, the columns don't match in such plaec in empty row. Here's an example of the initial data frame:

And here's the data frame:

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3
A    X    X     
B    Y    Q    Q
B              Y
C    Z         Z
D    P    P    Q
E    R 
F    R    S
```

and this is expected output

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3
A    X    X     
B    Y         Y
B         Q    Q
C    Z         Z
D    P    P      
D              Q        
E    R 
F    R     
F         S
```

I have aceive this using loop, but i want to do same job using either tider, dplyer, tidyverse, mutate, pivot_longer and pivot_wider, I tried but couldnt.

Could someone provide guidance or code examples on how to reorder and align columns based on matching values within rows while leaving empty cells for non-matching columns in R? Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify the difference between a "desired" and a "exptected" output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
quux %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  filter(nzchar(value)) %>%
  mutate(val2 = value) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, value), names_from = name, values_from = val2, values_fill = "") %>%
  select(-value)
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   ID    Col1  Col2  Col3 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     "X"   "X"   ""   
# 2 B     "Y"   ""    "Y"  
# 3 B     ""    "Q"   "Q"  
# 4 C     "Z"   ""    "Z"  
# 5 D     "P"   "P"   ""   
# 6 D     ""    ""    "Q"  
# 7 E     "R"   ""    ""   
# 8 F     "R"   ""    ""   
# 9 F     ""    "S"   ""
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Col1 = c("X", "Y", "", "Z", "P", "R", "R"), Col2 = c("X", "Q", "", "", "P", "", "S"), Col3 = c("", "Q", "Y", "Z", "Q", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

After a lengthy [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255647/discussion-between-r2evans-and-umar), the expected behavior changes slightly: namely, when in the presence of a repeat string (within on `Gene.ID` and one test): repeats should be on repeated rows.

The basic flow of this and my understanding of a working modification to the above:

```r
data <- structure(list(Gene.ID = c("g4260.t1", "g429.t1", "g429.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1"), HMMER = c("GH16", "GH3", "", "GH71", "", "", "GH27", "GH13"), eCAMI = c("", "GH13", "GH14", "CBM24", "CBM24", "GH27", "CBM13", "GH27"), DIAMOND = c("GH16", "", "", "GH71", "", "GH27", "CBM13", "GH13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
expected_data <- structure(list(Gene.ID = c("g4260.t1", "g429.t1", "g429.t1", "g429.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1"), HMMER = c("GH16", "GH3", "", "", "GH71", "", "", "GH27", "GH13", "", ""), eCAMI = c("", "", "GH13", "GH14", "", "CBM24", "CBM24", "GH27", "", "CBM13", "GH27"), DIAMOND = c("GH16", "", "", "", "GH71", "", "", "GH27", "GH13", "CBM13", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

I think the output should be:

```r
 pivot_longer(data, cols = -Gene.ID) %>%
  filter(nzchar(value)) %>%
  mutate(val2 = value, rn = row_number(), .by = c(Gene.ID, name, value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Gene.ID, value, rn), names_from = name, values_from = val2, values_fill = "") %>%
  select(-value, -rn)
# # A tibble: 11 × 4
#    Gene.ID  HMMER  DIAMOND eCAMI  
#    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
#  1 g4260.t1 "GH16" "GH16"  ""     
#  2 g429.t1  "GH3"  ""      ""     
#  3 g429.t1  ""     ""      "GH13" 
#  4 g429.t1  ""     ""      "GH14" 
#  5 g4300.t1 "GH71" "GH71"  ""     
#  6 g4300.t1 ""     ""      "CBM24"
#  7 g4300.t1 ""     ""      "CBM24"
#  8 g4303.t1 "GH27" "GH27"  "GH27" 
#  9 g4303.t1 ""     "CBM13" "CBM13"
# 10 g4303.t1 "GH13" "GH13"  ""     
# 11 g4303.t1 ""     ""      "GH27"
```

Comment: How did u do can u explain

Comment: I reshape wide-to-long (grouped only by `ID`) so that I can then reshape from long-to-wide grouping by ***both*** `ID` and the letters (`value`), which ensures that each new row has only instances of the letter in it (or an empty string). The extra `val2` is because `pivot_wider` will not allow any of the `id_cols` to be used in `*_from=` later in the arguments.

Comment: For reshaping long-to-wide, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272. For wide-to-long, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272; (names_pattern) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; (multiple value columns) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272.

Comment: Hi, but if i use for different dat set I am getting error
Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <character> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
suppose this data
data <- data.frame(
  Gene.ID = c("g4260.t1", "g429.t1", "g429.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4300.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1", "g4303.t1"),
  HMMER = c("GH16", "GH3", "", "GH71", "", "GH27", "GH27", "GH13"),
  eCAMI = c("GH16", "GH13", "GH14", "CBM24", "", "GH27", "CBM13", "GH27"),
  DIAMOND = c("GH16", "", "", "GH71", "", "GH27", "CBM13", "GH13")
)

Comment: If you go through `pivot_wider` _without_ the `values_fill=` arg, you'll see that `g4303.t1 GH27` has counts of 2 for both `HMMER` and `eCAMI`. What do you intend when you have duplicates? If you don't care that you have twice as many `g4303.t1 eCAMI   GH27` and `g4303.t1 HMMER   GH27` as everything else, then you can add `%>% distinct()` before your `pivot_wider`, but ... *that is deleting records*.

Comment: I have duplicate id, in such case how to handle , thanks for replying, should i change question,

Comment: You can ask that question all day long, but the question is not _how_ to do it (I just told you), it is **IF** one should do it. It is not a programming question, it is a question of meaning in your data. What does it mean to you that in your data, you have `GH27` in multiple rows of the same column for a particular `Gene.ID`? Is it significant, a quirk, a problem in the data, a redundancy you are comfortable dismissing, ...?

Comment: No, actualy, it's a domain or motif found in one protein, it can be multiple , and it identified by three different database, so I want to process in such a way, to get proper results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255647/discussion-between-r2evans-and-umar).

Comment: I cant chat anymore since it got colsed, I have edited my expected data
expected_data <- data.frame(
  'Gene.ID' = c('g4260.t1', 'g429.t1', 'g429.t1', 'g429.t1', 'g4300.t1', 'g4300.t1', 'g4300.t1', 'g4303.t1', 'g4303.t1', 'g4303.t1','g4303.t1'),
  'HMMER' = c('GH16', 'GH3', '', '', 'GH71', '', '', 'GH27', '', 'GH13',''),
  'eCAMI' = c('', '', 'GH13', 'GH14', '', 'CBM24', 'CBM24', 'GH27', 'CBM13', '','GH27'),
  'DIAMOND' = c('GH16', '', '', '', 'GH71', '', '', 'GH27', 'CBM13', 'GH13','')
)
i need this since it is part of analysis, sometime one protein hvae more domain even same