# ggplot geom_boxplot colour madness

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am manually combining boxplots with different y-axes and trying to make them pretty. For this example, I am using the mtcars df, so the plot is nonsensical, but it is a minimally reproducible example.

With the following code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp),
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=disp),
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6)
```

I get:

[image]

This is as it should be. But once I add fill, weird things start happening:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp, fill="green"),
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=disp, fill="red"),
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6)
```

Here, the left boxplot should be green and the right red, but:

[image]

and if I change the colours again:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp, fill="blue"),
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=disp, fill="blue"),
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6)
```

[image]

It does not seem to let me use anything other than red and blue. But even when I use only those colours, it assigns them strangely. It is not throwing any errors or warnings. I have a version with four boxplots that will let me use purple and green as well as red and blue, but it does this same weird colour assignment thing. Using hex codes does not help. Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Try adding the fill colour as an argument of `geom_boxplot` rather than inside `aes`, e.g. `geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp), position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), width=.3, alpha=.6, fill = 'red')`.  Inside the `aes` gets treated as a variable.

Comment: Great, thank you! If you make that an answer I'll give you the check mark :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `fill=` (and other aesthetics) are defined *outside* of the `aes(..)`, they are used verbatim, i.e., the color you provide is what is used. However, when the `fill=` or such are defined *inside* of the `aes(..)`, they are treated like variables, as if there is a column in the frame that has that unvarying value. This may be more clear if we change from using color-words to something else:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp, fill="HP Data"),
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=disp, fill="DISP Data"),
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6)
```

[image]

To manually assign specific colors to specific levels (i.e., `"HP Data"` is one level), use `scale_*_manual(values=..)`, and provide a named vector there.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=hp, fill="HP Data"),
               position = position_nudge(x=-0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  geom_boxplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=disp, fill="DISP Data"),
               position = position_nudge(x=0.2),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("HP Data"="green", "DISP Data"="red"))
```

[image]

In this case (not sure how your data is structured elsewhere), it is often better to reshape/pivot the data from a wide format to a long format. With this, you will only need to use `geom_boxplot` *once*, which can be particularly advantageous if you have more levels (and would have to type out `geom_boxplot(..)` for each column).

I'll pivot using `dplyr` (for `select`) and `tidyr::pivot_longer`, though there are other methods outside of the tidyverse if you prefer.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
select(mtcars, hp, disp) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) |>
  mutate(name = relevel(factor(name), "hp")) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=value, fill=name),
               width=.3, alpha=.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("hp"="green", "disp"="red"))
```

[image]

Notice the changes:

- `pivot_longer` (if you look at the intermediate results) now contains two variables, `name` (which has `"hp"` and `"disp"`) and `value` (all the numbers);
- one `geom_boxplot`, without the `position` nudging
- I changed the named vector to use the original names `"hp"` and `"disp"`, though you can certainly rename them in the original data if desired
- I used `relevel` solely to get the same order of variables: you were controlling which variables was on the left by manually controlling `position`, but lacking that then `ggplot` will put them in the order of the data, which is either alphabetic (strings) or the order as defined by `factor` (and `relevel`) when factors.

More info on pivoting/reshaping can be found at:

- [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272)
- [how to use pivot_longer in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272) (includes stats::reshape)
- (names_pattern) [Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272)
- (multiple value columns) [pivot_longer into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272) and [Is there way to pivot_longer to multiple values columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272)