# wide data with part of column name as value

Tags: r, reshape, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I have the following data structure in R

```
  DE_GDP DE_INFL US_GDP US_INFL
1      1       1      1       1
2      2       2      2       2
3      3       3      3       3
4      4       4      4       4
```

and I want to reshape it to this structure:

```
  GDP INFL COUNTRY
1   1    1      DE
2   2    2      DE
3   3    3      DE
4   4    4      DE
5   1    1      US
6   2    2      US
7   3    3      US
8   4    4      US
```

How is this possible?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, DE_GDP:US_INFL, names_to = c("Country", ".value"), names_sep = "_")`. See [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns).

Comment: Other links about reshaping from wide to long: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272 (includes stats::reshape); (names_pattern) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; (multiple value columns) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272